# Use tf.contrib.ffmpeg on gcp ml-engine instances

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

How can I use tf.contrib.ffmpeg in cloud ml-engine instances? It seems that the ffmpeg linux package is not installed by default on gcp ml-engine images and not available to be installed with pip.

Thanks,.

Comment: We have an alpha feature on Cloud ML Engine that allows you to submit your own container for training. This will allow you to customize your environment as desired. Please fill out the following form for access:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd62mhPwx4ty0u-K6HKZigV6H27DVmuZybRf3qzf81eNCuJ3g/viewform

Comment: I now have switched to use librosa via py_func, which is not great in performance but it is ok for now. I hope to enjoy Cloud ML alpha features some other time in the future. Thanks